# ruby restrict attr_accessor in subclass

Tags: ruby, inheritance, attr-accessor

I want restrict the access of superclass's method in subclass

```
class Parent
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name

  def initialize(first_name, last_name)
    @first_name, @last_name = first_name, last_name
  end

  def full_name
  @first_name + " " + @last_name 
  end

end

class Son < Parent
  attr_accessor :first_name

  def initialize(parent, first_name)
    @first_name = first_name 
    @last_name = parent.last_name
  end

  def full_name
    @first_name + "  " + @last_name 
  end
end


p = Parent.new("Bharat", "Chipli")
puts p.full_name

s = Son.new(p, "Harry")
s.last_name= "Smith"
puts s.full_name
```

here i am getting son's full name as **"Harry Smith"**, but i want **"Harry Chipli"**

Comment: One solution I can think of right now would be to redefine the `last_name=` method so it does nothing or throws an Exception for instance. This behavior could also be wrapped in a mixin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the initialize method of the parent:

```
@first_name, @last_name = [first_name, last_name]
```

try this

and:

```
class Son
  def attr_reader :last_name

  def last_name=(name)
    @last_name ||= name
  end
end
```

this way it will only define the last name if the son doesn't have the name set from parent (good for orphans).

Comment: still i can set last_name to child. What i need is If try to run son.last_name = 'something', an error 'last name must be taken from parent' should appear. Son can get last_name, but last_name is always the same as parent

Comment: then: def last_name=(name)
    raise "last name must be taken from parent"
  end

Answer (score 0):

```
class Son < Parent
  attr_accessor :first_name

  ...

  private

  attr_accessor :last_name
end
```

should do it.

Comment: thanks, but it give error when i access the parent's lasat_name inside Son's initialize method "@last_name = parent.last_name"

Comment: what is the best way to access parent's last_name from son's instance?, some thing like attr_reader :last_name in son will give parent's last_name

Comment: I think you're better off not using inheritance at all for this problem. What happens if the son goes into the witness protection programme and is given a new last name?

Comment: what i actually need is this, If try to run son.last_name = 'something', an error 'last name must be taken from parent' should appear. Son can get last_name, but last_name is always the same as parent. Because last_name should be his parent name and not any name set by son himself

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the last_name setter:

```
Class Son < Parent

...

def last_name=(name)
end
```